# Sonarqube warned sql injection on the input-driven column name in my hibernate sql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sonarqube, sql-injection

My java (Hibernate, MySql) code takes the input data to decide which column I want to update as below:

```
String hsql = "update People set " + inputColumnName + " = null";
Query query = myHibernateSession.createQuery(hsql);
query.executeUpdate();
```

However, Sonarqube said "Change this code to not construct SQL queries directly from user-controlled data". Anyway I can avoid this error (either fix this or by-pass sonarqube check without turn this rule off)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the variable to be a column name and remove potential for insertion of a statement. Using bind variables would help but take a look at some examples such as these: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html